# Use SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH to aggregate values

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

I would like to generate a data hierarchy.

This query:

```
select  connect_by_root(parent_id) as root_id
        ,ID, NAME
        ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PARENT_ID,'/') PATH
        ,level
        ,line
        ,LINE*power(10,-level+1) CALC
        ,ltrim(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(lpad(LINE,3,'0'), '.'),'.')  SORT
from    (

  select 3 ID, 1 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 4 ID, 2 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 5 ID, 3 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 6 ID, 1 LINE, 5 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 7 ID, 1 LINE, 6 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL

) v
start with v.parent_id = 2
connect by nocycle prior id=parent_id
```

Generates:

```
ROOT_ID ID PATH     LEVEL   LINE    CALC    SORT
2       3   /2      1       1       1       001
2       4   /2      1       2       2       002
2       5   /2      1       3       3       003
2       6   /2/5    2       1       0.1     003.001
2       7   /2/5/6  3       1       0.01    003.001.001
```

What I would like:

```
ROOT_ID ID PATH     LEVEL   LINE    CALC    
2       3   /2      1       1       1       
2       4   /2      1       2       2       
2       5   /2      1       3       3       
2       6   /2/5    2       1       3.1     
2       7   /2/5/6  3       1       3.11
```

Is there a way to get `sys_connect_by_path` (or another function) to tally the `CALC` column and its parents?

Currently, I'm using the `SORT` field for ordering the rows; I'd rather sort on a proper numerical value (`CALC` field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  connect_by_root(parent_id) as root_id
        ,ID
        ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PARENT_ID,'/') PATH
        ,level
        ,line
        ,LINE*power(10,-level+1) CALC
        ,XMLCAST(XMLQUERY(ltrim(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(LINE*power(10,-level+1), '+'),'+') RETURNING CONTENT) AS NUMBER) SORT
from    (

  select 3 ID, 1 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 4 ID, 2 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 5 ID, 3 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 6 ID, 1 LINE, 5 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 7 ID, 1 LINE, 6 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL

) v
start with v.parent_id = 2
connect by nocycle prior id=parent_id
```

Comment: Nice!  I was thinking that an `eval` function would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may take your `SORT` column and after some fidling (changing the first dot to comma and removing other dots) convert the result to a number.

The key part is here

```
 to_number(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(SORT,'\.',',',1,1),'\.',null),
   '99D9999' , ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ') sort2
```

Example
`3.1.1`  -> `3,1.1`  -> `3,11` and convert to number

The complete query here

```
with v as (
  select 3 ID, 1 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 4 ID, 2 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 5 ID, 3 LINE, 2 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 6 ID, 1 LINE, 5 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 7 ID, 1 LINE, 6 PARENT_ID FROM DUAL

), v2 as (
select  connect_by_root(parent_id) as root_id
        ,ID 
        ,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PARENT_ID,'/') PATH
        ,level my_level
        ,line
        ,LINE*power(10,-level+1) CALC
        ,ltrim(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( LINE , '.'),'.')  SORT
from     v
start with v.parent_id = 2
connect by nocycle prior id=parent_id
)
select ROOT_ID, ID, PATH, my_level, LINE, CALC, SORT,
to_number(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(SORT,'\.',',',1,1),'\.',null),'99D9999' , ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ') sort2
from v2
```